# How to automatically hyperlink BibTeX citations?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyperref, citing, hyperlink

Imagine I have a .bib entry as follows

```
@article{blow2011dormant,
  title={How dormant origins promote complete genome replication},
  author={Blow, J Julian and Ge, Xin Quan and Jackson, Dean A},
  journal={Trends in biochemical sciences},
  volume={36},
  number={8},
  pages={405--414},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

which was obtained from the BibTeX [citation in Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=How%20dormant%20origins%20promote%20complete%20genome%20replication&btnG=). Is it possible to automatically create the hyperlink to this paper?

**Some thoughts:** I imagine I would have to manually include the `url` in the bib item, and use `hyperref`, but could we maybe automate a way of linking the Google Scholar search based on the item? For example, something like

```
\href{https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q= + "STRING" + &btnG=}{item details}}
```

where `"STRING"` would be a string composed of the authors' names and the title. I just want to avoid having to manually add each entry, unless there is a way to export the BibTeX citation that includes the link. Any ideas?

Comment: instead of an url or, worse, a google scholar search, you should include the doi of the article: `10.1016/j.tibs.2011.05.002`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz when exporting from Google Scholar, I believe the doi is not included in the BibTeX version of the citation. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Could I use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63975079/auto-fill-the-url-field-from-the-doi-field-in-jabref), with JabRef?

Comment: ... fix it by not downloading from google scholar? The bibtex export from the journal website includes the doi

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz fair enough